# How do I do an upstream soql with the nested columns to the stage of the most recent opportunity for each campaign member

Tags: soql

```
SELECT Id,
            ( Select  (SELECT OpportunityId.Stagename FROM OpportunityContactRole ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Contact)
         FROM CampaignMember limit 10
```

This is my super nested soql in an attempt to get at this data, but it's compaining because it doesn't understand the relationship.  What's the right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used.

```
[Select  (select id, createddate from fancytable__r where status__c = 'Open'  order by createddate desc limit 1), (SELECT Opportunity.Stagename, Opportunity.Id FROM OpportunityContactRoles where not Opportunity.stagename like 'Closed%' ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 1), (select CampaignMember.id, CampaignMember.Campaign.Name from campaignmembers order by createddate desc limit 1) FROM Contact where id in :id]
```

The tricky bit is to only go down stream from parent to child etc.  So, if the entry is the cm, you have to collect the relevant loc id's and then get the cm joined with the other data using the above.  Unfortunate limitation.  I would be really cool if I were or will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing a big, long answer, but I came to the realization that what you're asking for cannot be accomplished with a single query.

The long and short of it is that we cannot do both the "most recent Opp for each CampaignMember" part and the "let's traverse a somewhat complex object hierarchy" part in a single query.

You'd need to use Aggregate Functions (and GROUP BY) or process query results in apex to be able to find the most recent Opp for more than just one person, and we can't use parent-child subqueries in grouped queries.

So you'll need at least 2 queries here, probably 3, and probably do some processing in Apex. Unfortunately, leading you through this would involve more time than I'm willing to offer for this question.